# JAX-RS retrieve Entity parameter from post Response java

Tags: java, rest, post, jax-rs

I am trying to retrieve entities from body response of a POST request

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig());
    Response response = client.target(url)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(form,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class);
    Log.trackingResponse(url, response);`
```

request is 200 OK, parameters I want to retrieve exist, I can see them while debugging:

[image]

My problem is I can not access these parameters.

I tried the following solution but it was not successful:

```
Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = clientResponse.readEntity(Map.class);
```

MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException

```
Order order = response.readEntity(Order.class);
```

Order being a custom class with Jacksonannotation, MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException

```
 String jsonResponse = clientResponse.readEntity(String.class);
```

returns  < ! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ....
the whote html code, but not my parameters

My maven has the correc jackson depedency.

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the status is 200? Where do you see that? What's the content of the HTML?

Comment: HI, yes 200% sure its 200 OK. I can see it while debugging as well
InboundJaxrsResponse{ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://domain/api/omni/login, status=200, reason=OK}}

Comment: Maybe I tried solution that should be correct, but that I do not apply them correctly, althought I can not see my mistakes yet.. :(

Comment: the content of the HTML is the Client side html + js from which the POST has been triggered

Comment: Are you sure your server endpoint is rest API?

Comment: Yes I am sure it is

Comment: Sounds like something you need to work out with the server and find out why it's returning HTML.

Comment: Is your server by chance sending a redirect response?

Comment: So the HTML in the response is the HTML from the client page that submitted the request?

Comment: I dont think it does. althought I am not sure to get the technical meaning.

Comment: @dbreaux yes it is.

Comment: I tried to build a POST method using Java HttpURLConnection, but I got HTML code as answer as well

Comment: Ok, what JAX-RS library are you using? It definitely looks like `Entity` is only where the *request* Entity goes, not overwritten by the *response* Entity. Or maybe in some specific case(s) it's not overwritten? Can you see the network messages and confirm that both request and response look the way they should?

Comment: my version is
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.6</version>
  </dependency>
I tried to curl the POST request from the server, I also get HTML content as an answer, so the response does not look like it should be

Answer (score 0):

These parameters are part of the request you sent, not the response.
They are members of the `form` you sent in the request entity:

```
.post(Entity.entity(form,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class);
```